# Why my Visual Studio project needs Node.js?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I just exported one of my VS2012 projects to VS2019 and the difference in memory consumption is huge, I noted that VS2019 creates a Node.Js process for my Project, but I don't use Node.js at all, can I configure VS2019 to not create a Node.js process for my Project?

Here is the difference of memory usage: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZ66p.jpg

Comment: For the last version or two (true in VS2017, can't recall for VS2015) significant pieces of functionality have been moved out of process, much of this hosted Node.Js. But questions of the design of VS really need to be addressed to the VS team.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions of the implementation of a commercial software product should go to the developers of that product.

Comment: It's exactly as @Richard says.  Most notably, the TypeScript/JavaScript language service is now hosted in a node.exe process, so all of the intellisense etc for those languages has this dependency.

Comment: @Jimmy, I'm not using typescript at all.

Comment: @user2070369 I gave that as just example, as it's one of the main ones that most web developers would notice when upgrading from VS2012.  And it applies equally to JS as much as TS.  There are other features also using node.exe, though I can't make an exhaustive list of them here.